# Exception 'key is too short to encrypt any messages' when trying to use RSA encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I'm trying to build a small encryption C++ library for Android with Crypto++.

I've built the library and I'm testing parts of it on Linux (x64) to see if everything's alright. Note that I almost have no experience with C++ coding and I'm mostly copying the Crypto++ wiki.

I'm having an issue with my RSA encryption function. I load a public key from two `CryptoPP::Integers` and then try to encrypt a message. I always get this exception from the try/catch statement:

> RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1): this key is too short to encrypt any messages

I've looked at Crypto++'s code and this seems to come from this exact part (code [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/pubkey_8cpp_source.html)):

```
if (plaintextLength > FixedMaxPlaintextLength())
{
    if (FixedMaxPlaintextLength() < 1)
      throw InvalidArgument(AlgorithmName() + ": this key is too short to encrypt any messages");
    ...
}
```

Conversely, [the Crypto++ wiki says](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) about FixedMaxPlaintextLength:

> The maximum length of a plaintext string that can be encrypted with RSA can be determined by FixedMaxPlaintextLength. On error, FixedMaxPlaintextLength returns 0. The value returned by FixedMaxPlaintextLength is directly related to the modulus size n and the padding scheme.

I'm compiling with:

```
g++ code.cpp -lcrypto++
```

An excerpt from my code is below. Know that I'm encrypting a message short enough for this key size, and that the key passes the 'ThrowIfInvalid' check fine.

```
#include <crypto++/rsa.h>
#include <crypto++/integer.h>
#include <crypto++/osrng.h>
#include <crypto++/aes.h>
#include <crypto++/modes.h>
#include <crypto++/filters.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

//Server public key
CryptoPP::Integer n("151819660278907849564280096608257132054351407309758535974318074707969518724128280259037374014724406632325172752862895193195363199223664682104258638634769874466650499673675383641901147871521771256322561247704585104482417607961937338394672732384692437499643518759317209830786970636267836539513421170177732815387");
CryptoPP::Integer e("65537");

std::string EncryptWithRSA(std::string message);

int main(){
    std::cout << "Input string: " << std::endl;
    std::string message = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    std::string result = "";
    result = EncryptWithRSA(message);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string EncryptWithRSA(std::string message){
    CryptoPP::Integer n("151819660278907849564280096608257132054351407309758535974318074707969518724128280259037374014724406632325172752862895193195363199223664682104258638634769874466650499673675383641901147871521771256322561247704585104482417607961937338394672732384692437499643518759317209830786970636267836539513421170177732815387");
    CryptoPP::Integer e("65537");
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    pubKey.Initialize(n, e);
    pubKey.ThrowIfInvalid(rng, 3);
    std::cout << "Public key initialized and validated" << std::endl;
    CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor enc(pubKey);
    std::string result = "";
    std::cout << "Starting encryption with RSA" << std::endl;
    try{
        CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(message, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc, new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));
    } catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}
```

***EDITED***
Here's the output for an Input string = "s"

```
Input string:
s
Public key initialized
Starting encryption with RSA
RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1): this key is too short to encrypt any messages
```

Comment: You are missing some information. We need to know what the string is. The public key is 128 bytes, so the max message size is going to be 85 bytes or so. I cannot duplicate the problem with 0-length messages and short messages. You might also be interested in [Android (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_(Command_Line)) on the wiki.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the output for a single-character string which it should be able to encrypt. I understand this must have something to do with the OS/some other thing if it's working fine for you. Many thanks!

Comment: In your `EncryptWithRSA` function, add a `std::cout << n.ByteCount() << std::endl;` And maybe add a `pubKey.MaxPlaintextLength();`.